# Read init params of workflow after it started

Tags: 2010, workflow, debugging

There's a sharepoint 2010 site of which I'm administrator. This site has a library with many items and workflows.
One of the workflows is behaving wrong. I would like to look at the initialization parameters of this workflow to diagnose the error. Is there a way a can do this without new code being deployed?

Thanks

EDIT: To clarify, I'm not looking for the workflow current status, I'm looking for the data inserted by the workflow originator at the start of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the workflow status in the workflow status page. To do this follow the instructions in [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc299037.aspx) technet article.

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not the info I'm looking for...